# Azure Active Directory B2C shows two different locations for the same tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created five B2C tenants in EU West, all in the same EU West based resource group.
[image: Resource group EU West]
[image]

When I navigate to cost analysis it shows that it is based in the US.

[image: Same Resource Group but shows US]
[image: Same Resource Group but shows US]

It is a must that all the user data will be stored in EU West (Amsterdam). Which is why this is concerning.
Am I missing something, or is this a visual bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one resource group in **West Europe** Location and created 2 **`B2C tenants`** in the same group as below:

[image]

When I checked **Cost analysis** tab, it is showing **`EU West`** as ***Location*** like below:

[image]

I checked the same in **Cost analysis (Preview)** tab and got the same location as below:

[image]

In your last screenshot, I can see **Unassigned** under Subscriptions for all those B2C tenants which may be the issue.

Please recheck whether the **B2C tenants** are linked with ***right subscription*** or not by visiting their **`Overview`** page like below:

[image]

Comment: It does indeed show that the subscription is Unassigned, although when I select one of them the overview shows that it is using the intended subscription. Is it possible that it shows Unassigned and us east by default when the money spend is still 0?

Comment: Yes, that also possible. It may take `us east` as **default** when you have not spent any. Try checking the same after spending some amount.

Answer (score 0):

The resource group might be in US, but if you go into the AADB2C tenant, and view it’s properties, it’ll state it’s DC location properly.

Comment: The first image shows that the resource group, AzureActiveDirectoryB2C, is located in West Europe. The only place where it shows US is when I am in the cost management/analysis tab.

Comment: The only menu that matters is the one I mention. The properties in the Azure AD b2C tenant via the AAD Blade.